# Fhir 500 error, involving extension

Tags: hl7-fhir

I'm new to fhir but I have the concept down I believe. I'm trying to do these activities just to understand it better but for this one I'm getting a error 500. I'm pretty sure I have the Post url correct. Ps i did the * on purpose I had my data in them thats way.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Patient xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://hl7.org/fhir file:/C:/Users/s*****/fhir-all-xsd/patient.xsd">
<text>
    <status value="generated"></status>
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <p>Berzerkistan Ministry of Health, April 25, 2016 -BMOHORB #150</p>
        <p>BMHO Patient Resource Constraints</p>
        <p>Gender:male</p>
        <p>BirthDate:****-**-**</p>
        <p>Given:***</p>
        <p>Family:***</p>
        <p>Identifier:www.berzerkistan.gov/bni</p>
        <p>Identifier:www.berzerkistan.gov/nhib</p>
    </div>  
</text>
<modifierExtension url="http://fhir.hl7fundamentals.org/berzerkistan/StructureDefinition/PatientTaxSituation">
    <valueCode value="Coding"></valueCode>
</modifierExtension>
<identifier>
    <use value = "usual"></use>
    <value value = "****.***"></value>
</identifier>
<identifier>
    <system value="www.berzerkistan.gov/bni"/>
    <value value="123"/>
</identifier>
<identifier>
    <system value="www.berzerkistan.gov/nhib"/>
    <value value="123"/>
</identifier>
<name>
    <family value="***"></family>
    <given value="***"></given>
</name>
<gender value="male"></gender>
<birthDate value="****-**-**"></birthDate>
</Patient>
```

[image: Activity]
[image: Result]

Comment: This error has nothing to do with your extension (it's incorrect anyway, check examples on the FHIR DSTU site). And next time, please don't share your assignment with others. Ask your tutor directly.

Answer (score 0):

The birthDate is definitely invalid.  And you're not supposed to have a schema declaration.  In theory either of those things could have caused the error.  However, if you're triggering a 500, it means the server is broken.  It's either not properly handling your invalid inputs or it's got something else going wrong.  Try sending to a few different servers.  Fix the errors those servers detect, then see if that fixes the problem with your first server.  (Also report the bug in the server raising the 500 error.)

Comment: Ive already sent an email to the server manager to check the status of it. Regarding birthDate I pretty sure its correct because that the formate it wants as you can see above, and Ive also seen it like that in the courses Ive been doing, and about the schema you are correct I just read about that. I didn't know that Thanks!

Comment: The birth date wouldn't be valid having asterisks in it.  It would have to be a valid date.

Comment: Oh thats what you meant, I know that I just didn't include them here for reasons.